# Fill post form with libcurl and get the final url

Tags: c++, openssl, libcurl

I need to authorize on site using C++ and libcurl
Site has complex url and using https
Site returning form with

```
Login field:
<input type="text" maxlength="64" name="edit[id]" id="edit-id" size="60" value="" class="form-text required">
Password field:
<input type="password" name="edit[pass]" id="edit-pass" value="" maxlength="20" size="30" class="form-text required">
Submit button:
<input type="submit" name="op" value="Log in" id="account_login_submit" class="form-submit submit_button button" data-role="none">
```

When you entering correct login-password pair, site redirecting you to another page with &token=... code in GET parameters

My current code:

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://url/dialog/oauth?");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "edit[id]=login&edit[pass]=password");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L); 

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    char url[256];
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL, &url);
    printf("final [%s]\n");
}
```

Now it returns nothing in CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL, and html code of form in verbosity log

Answer (score 0):

First, you're using `curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL..)` wrong, as you should pass in a pointer to a `char *`, but your code passes in a pointer to a char buffer. I've added an example to the [CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL.html) man page now to show it better.

But ultimately you should probably not use this option, as it is intended to show the URL *it would redirect to, if you didn't ask libcurl to redirect* - and you asked libcurl to follow redirects (with [CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html)).

If you want to figure out the URL libcurl redirects to, use [CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL.html) instead. That page also has an example (now) to show how it is used.